# Validation search field in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, but I just can not make it work. What according to you is the problem?

```
<div class="box-search">
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return doSearch('search-form','text_cautat');" id="search-form">
    <input type="text" name="s" class="search-field" id="text_cautat" value="" maxlength="100" placeholder="Cauta" />
    <select class="search-cat select-menu" name="categorie" id="cat_cautare">
        <option value="0">Toate</option>
        <option value="211">Accesorii GSM</option>
        <option value="406">Laptopuri &amp; Tablete</option>
        <option value="193">Componente PC</option>
        <option value="416">Periferice</option>
        <option value="1364">Gaming PC &amp; Console</option>
        <option value="192">Foto &amp; Video</option>
        <option value="233">Electronice</option>
        <option value="219">Auto</option>
        <option value="1378">Telefoane</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Cerca" onclick="return doSearch('search-form','text_cautat');" class="search-button" />
</form>
```

and JS:

```
function doSearch(id_form, id_camp) {
var search_string = $(id_camp).value;

//trim
search_string = trim(search_string);

var search_form = $(id_form);

if (search_string.length < 3) {
    alert("Minimo 3 caratteri!");
    return false;
} else {
    var cuvinte_split = search_string.split(" ");

    search_string = search_string.replace(/-/g, "_");
    search_string = search_string.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9_.]/g, "-");
    search_form.action = "http://www.website.com/cerca/" + search_string;
        search_form.submit();
        return true;
    }
}

function trim(str, chars) {
    return ltrim(rtrim(str, chars), chars);
}

function ltrim(str, chars) {
    chars = chars || "\\s";
    return str.replace(new RegExp("^[" + chars + "]+", "g"), "");
}

function rtrim(str, chars) {
    chars = chars || "\\s";
    return str.replace(new RegExp("[" + chars + "]+$", "g"), "");
}
```

The script should allow the searching have been entered only if at least three characters. But it does not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP8R9/

Comment: quick description of what its supposed to do???

Comment: When posting a question to stackoverflow, please include as much detail as possible.  Saying something doesn't work won't help us help you. Please include errors you get and what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Ok, I added a few details. Now the question is more complete?

Comment: `var search_string = $('#' + id_camp).val();`

Comment: Well! But now the script does not send me the form here: `search_form.action = "http://www.website.com/cerca/" + search_string;`

Comment: I thought this question was about the fact that your 3 character validation was not working? That sounds like a further question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When searching for an ID, the [selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) needs to start with `#`.
2. You also should be using [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
3. And why not consider using jQuery's [`trim`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
4. Also look at [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and consider using jQuery's
   [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
5. If you are going to post a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ZP8R9/2/) that uses jQuery, make sure
   to also include the library.
6. Checking what was logged (and posting it here) in the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Debugging_JavaScript)
   would have led you to the problem.

Comment: Well! But now the script does not send me the form here: `search_form.action = "http://www.website.com/cerca/" + search_string;`

Comment: `var search_form = $('#' + id_form);` Seems you didn't learn anything from the answer posted here.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `$(sector)` to create a jQuery object from DOM, like `$('#search-form')`
Based on your code, you should probably change `onsubmit` to

```
onsubmit="return doSearch('#search-form','#text_cautat');"
```